# Multi Colored Smoke

Tags: shaders, physics, smoke-simulation

I have two emitters in a smoke simulation (2.9). I want them to both emit different colors of smoke. How should I do this? The two colors of smoke should also interact with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the smoke colour in the smoke emitter properties :

[image: smoke color]

In the Shader Editor you can use the Volume Info node to feed the Color into the volume shader :

[image: smoke color nodes]

Comment: Thanks, I never thought it was this simple. Can the colors mix?

Comment: @EricXue Glad to help. Yes - the smoke can mix and will result in a blend of the colors.

Comment: As a side note, you need to re-bake simulations for the color to be taken into account